# Origen de la palabra "chisme"

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, sustantivos

Este fin de semana he tenido conversaciones que pueden dar para varias preguntas, así que vamos allá.

Empezamos por un descubrimiento curioso. En una de dichas conversaciones surgió la palabra "[chisme](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8tUu95T)", que básicamente es sinónimo de "[cotilleo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B8zW99j)" y de "[cacharro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6W3NjZG)" (se usó en el primer sentido mencionado). Cuando fui al diccionario a consultar su significado exacto, al final lo que me sorprendió más fue su etimología:

> Del lat. *schisma*, y este del gr. *σχίσμα schísma* 'escisión, separación'.

Oh, wait, yo conozco otra palabra que me juego lo que quieras a que tiene la misma etimología:

> **[cisma](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9Lbbywe)**
>
> Del lat. *schisma*, y este del gr. *σχίσμα schísma* 'escisión,
>   separación'.
>
> 1. m. División o separación en el seno de una iglesia o religión. Era u. t. c. f.
> 2. m. Escisión, discordia, desavenencia.

Esta última palabra tiene mucho más sentido que tenga la etimología que tiene, dado que su significado es prácticamente el original. Pero como sabemos, los caminos de la lengua son inescrutables. Así que tratemos de escrutarlos.

¿Cómo dio origen la palabra "cisma" a la palabra "chisme", cuyas dos acepciones son coloquiales? ¿Cuándo se originó esta?

Comment: No sé; pero he visto muchas situaciones donde dos personas sufrieron una escisión debido a un chisme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que en este caso Covarrubias tiene la solución, dado que en su definición de *chisme* se quedó bastante a gusto (grafías adaptadas para mejorar la comprensión lectora):

> CHISME, y chismeria. Chismoso, el que va con nuevas a otro de cosa que deviera callarla, por aversela fiado, y ser secreta, y dicha en perjuycio de la persona a quien lo revela, de que ha de tomar desgusto, y lo cuenta con malicia para rebolver y causar diferencias; y assi refiere las cosas por el peor termino que puede. Estos son ciçañeros, que siembran discordias entre los hermanos; ministros de Satanas.

Y tras haberse quedado tranquilo, comienza a disertar sobre las posibles etimologías. Una de ellas hace referencia a la que ahora está aceptada por la RAE, y que demuestra que @aparente no iba desencaminado con [su comentario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/9385/aparente001).

> Chisme se pudo dezir del nombre Griego, schisma.atis, que vale discordia, y dissension, porque el chismoso no pretende otra cosa, como hemos dicho arriba: o sea del sonido que haze hablando a la oreja, porque los circunstantes no perciben sino el sonido de chis, chis.

Por tanto, la etimología proveniente del griego tendría un doble motivo: el de causar un cisma entre las personas, y a la vez onomatopéyico (el sonido *chis, chis* también es mencionado por Covarrubias en otras palabras que implican una transmisión de sonido, como *chiste*).

Lo curioso es que si nos vamos a 1495, Nebrija en su diccionario español-latino decide traducir *chisme* no al latino, sino al griego:

> Chisme en griego. schisma.atis.

Ya en 1516 se encuentran otras acepciones, como:

> Chisme o chinche. cimer.cimicis.
>   Chisme o chismeria. nuge.arum.

Sí, al parecer *chisme* era sinónimo de *chinche* hacia el siglo XVI. De hecho Percival en 1591 solo da para *chisme* la misma acepción que para *chinche*, aunque también incluye *chismería* (*trifles*) y *chisma* (*a schisme*). Comenzando el siglo XVII algunos diccionarios aparte del de Covarrubias ya recogen para *chisme* la traducción al francés como *bourde, baverie, gaberies, rapport, frivoles*, indicando que se dice así por el sentido de *división* que tiene *schisma*, y de hecho *chismero* lo definen como *sembrador de discordia*.

En el CORDE los primeros casos son del siglo XV:

> *E fázenles mantener lo que dixieren e pusieren e a fablar todavía verdat. E non les abezen fin consientan ser chismeros o acusadores d'otro.*
>
> Enrique de Villena, "Arte cisoria", 1423 (España).

Nótese el uso de *chismeros*: generadores de cismas.